# Declare variable-length array as a config value with Snakemake CLI

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, snakemake

I have a Snakemake workflow where one of the top-level config entries is an array of variable size (in this particular example, a sibling may or may not be included in the analysis). Currently I'm using the following config file.

```
{
    "case": "/scratch/standage/12175/BAMs/12175.proband.bam",
    "controls": [
        "/scratch/standage/12175/BAMs/12175.mother.bam",
        "/scratch/standage/12175/BAMs/12175.father.bam"
    ]
}
```

I know snakemake allows one to specify config options on the command line with the `--config` flag. Since the `case` value is a single string, this is trivial to do on the command line. But what about the `controls` value(s)? Is it possible to pass an array/list of values as one of the config options on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to pass an array/list of values as one of the config options on the command line

I doubt that is directly possible, but you could pass a quoted string of space (or comma or whatever) separated values that you split to list inside the Snakefile:

```
snakemake -C controls='control1 control2 ...'
```

Then inside the Snakefile:

```
controls= config['controls'].split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to pass variables on the command line like so...

```
snakemake --config case=proband.bam control1=mother.bam control2=father.bam
```

...and then to parse the configuration settings dynamically in the Snakefile. For example, any config key matching the regular expression `control\d+` corresponds to a control sample.

So it's possible, but a bit of a stretch, and the config file is probably the better/cleaner option.